# Is this decorator type-annotated correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

```
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Callable


def timer(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    """Calculates the runtime of a function, and outputs it to logging.DEBUG."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + "." + func.__name__)
        _logger.debug(" runtime: {:.4f} seconds".format(end - start))
        return value

    return wrapper
```

Comment: Maybe, instead of adding random Latin, you could have actually explained what you're trying to do with your code so we could understand what you're doing. You can't post just code for a reason...

Comment: The code works fine, and it's very basic. I just want to know if the function is type-annotated correctly (which was the question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Python 3.10, you can easily preserve all type information through a decorator using [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec):

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def timer(func: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    """Calculates the runtime of a function, and outputs it to logging.DEBUG."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        start = perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + "." + func.__name__)
        _logger.debug(" runtime: {:.4f} seconds".format(end - start))
        return value

    return wrapper
```

---

(For python < 3.10, but prefer juanpa.arrivillaga's answer to preserve information on the input types)

Indentation seems a bit off here, but otherwise, yes, the types aren't incorrect. You could make this a bit more precise, though. The function you output has the same return type as the function taken as input, but you don't note this.

In particular, you can say something like

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
def timer(func: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[..., T]:
```

It seems like you should be able to do the same with the args/kwargs, but I haven't come across that case in my own typing experience, so I can't say exactly how. EDIT - See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/193) for more about typing those; it doesn't seem possible (yet?).

I suppose you could also say

```py
def timer(func: T) -> T:
```

but that doesn't seem as useful.

Answer (score 12):

The problem with this approach is that now, MyPy loses the return type, or rather, it degenerates into `Any`, so consider:

```
import logging
from typing import Callable, Any
from time import perf_counter
from functools import wraps

def timer(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    """Calculates the runtime of a function, and outputs it to logging.DEBUG."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + func.__name__)
        _logger.debug(' runtime: {:.4f} seconds'.format(end - start))
        return value
    return wrapper

@timer
def func(x:int) -> int:
    return x


def string_func(s: str):
    return s[:]

x = 42 * func(42)

reveal_type(x)

string_func(x)
```

Using:

```
(py37) Juans-MacBook-Pro:tempdata juan$ mypy --version
mypy 0.641
```

If I try to type-check this, it passes!

```
(py37) Juans-MacBook-Pro:tempdata juan$ mypy typing_decorators.py
typing_decorators.py:29: error: Revealed type is 'Any'
```

I've found one solution in the case where you want to *preserve exactly* the arguments, which is to use a `TypeVar` and to `cast` the wrapper, that way MyPy can know exactly the type (assuming the original function is annoated):

```
import logging
from typing import Callable, Any, TypeVar, cast
from time import perf_counter
from functools import wraps


F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def timer(func: F) -> F:
    """Calculates the runtime of a function, and outputs it to logging.DEBUG."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.' + func.__name__)
        _logger.debug(' runtime: {:.4f} seconds'.format(end - start))
        return value
    return cast(F, wrapper)

@timer
def func(x:int) -> int:
    return x


def string_func(s: str):
    return s[:]

x = 42 * func(42)

reveal_type(x)

string_func(x)
```

In this case:

```
(py37) Juans-MacBook-Pro:tempdata juan$ mypy typing_decorators.py
typing_decorators.py:32: error: Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
typing_decorators.py:34: error: Argument 1 to "string_func" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

Comment: would you say that Nathan's solution is easier? less code, same result

Comment: btw, thank you for the lengthy explanation, I've learned a lot

Comment: I'm admittedly not familiar with `typing.cast`, but this solution seems better than mine. As in my second example, it does say that the output type is exactly the input type, but using `cast(F, wrapper)` will, if I understand correctly, return a function which has the exact same type signature as the input function did (not only the return value but also whatever args/kwargs). As demonstrated, `mypy` understands the types correctly here, though testing the input to the wrapped func may have been more useful, since typing the output correctly is easier; I assume that works too.

Comment: I wonder if this approach also works well in, e.g., VS Code? Would it warn me if I try to pass a string as input to the wrapped `func`, which should only take a single `int`? Or is that too complicated for however type hints are handled in IDEs? I haven't really used `mypy` and mostly just get told by VS Code if it thinks something is wrong.

Comment: @Nathan it is important to understand that `cast` just *returns exactly the same object*. It merely is a signal to static analyzers.