# The IDE does not see the return type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Suppose there is a `Message` class:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, id_: int, text: str):
        self.id = id_
        self.text = text
```

There is also a `send_message` method inside the `Account` class, which returns an instance of the `Message` class:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def send_message(self, chat_id: int, text: str) -> Message:
        message_id = ...  # Makes a request to send a message and gets the message ID from the response
        return Message(message_id, text)
```

If I then use the `send_message` method and try to get the text property from the instance returned by this method, the IDE will give me the `Message` class property list as it should be. Also, if I don't pass enough arguments, the IDE will let me know.

[image]

Now I wrap the `send_message` method in `my_decorator` (I also specify type hints in the decorator):

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec


PARAMS = ParamSpec("PARAMS")
RETURN_VAL = TypeVar("RETURN_VAL")


def my_wrapper(func: Callable[PARAMS, RETURN_VAL]) -> Callable[PARAMS, RETURN_VAL]:
    def wrapper(*args: PARAMS.args, **kwargs: PARAMS.kwargs) -> RETURN_VAL:
        # do some staff
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    
    @my_wrapper
    def send_message(self, chat_id: int, text: str) -> Message:
        message_id = ...  # Makes a request to send a message and gets the message ID from the response
        return Message(message_id, text)
```

And because of this type hints break: now I'm not shown a list of properties and methods of `Message` class, and if I don't pass enough arguments, the IDE won't tell me anything about it.

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

P.S.: if `send_message` is outside the `Account` class, the type hints work, but I need `send_message` to be **inside** the `Account` class.

```
@my_wrapper
def send_message(chat_id: int, text: str) -> Message:
    message_id = ...  # Makes a request to send a message and gets the message ID from the response
    return Message(message_id, text)
```

[image]

Comment: You say "the IDE", but you haven't named or tagged one. Is this PyCharm?

Comment: @Chris, I have tried several IDEs, none of them show me any hints on the return type. Including PyCharm.

Comment: What if you just make a single `TypeVar(bound=Callable)` and have that be the parameter to your decorator?  That's the way I usually annotate decorators if I don't need to transform the parameters or the return type.  The `ParamSpec` stuff is relatively new and it might be that your IDE's language plugin doesn't grok it yet.

Comment: @Samwise, I don't really understand exactly what you are suggesting. Could you please show me some example code?

Comment: @Samwise it's going to require a `cast` to get things to work correctly, IIUC

Comment: So, as an example, [this is how I was solving this years ago when mypy was still very young](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964760/is-this-decorator-type-annotated-correctly/54964857#54964857) Note, there is no guarantee PyCharm will understand these things.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for the example, but like you said, PyCharm doesn't understand it.

Comment: @Woopertail yeah, I'm not sure what you want us to tell you. Note, VSCode with Pylance (which uses Pyright) seems to understand it fine... by that I mean your original `ParamSpec` version.